# How can I execute a javascript function on text field input and update the field with new value

Tags: javascript

I use a javascript function to find the src string in an iframe tag and return the found src string, and it works correctly alone, but I need to use it on a text input field to grab the iframe src on input paste, and update the same field with the new value returned by the function.

The search function works correctly

```
function findSrc(str, pointa, pointb) 
{
  var str = " "+str;
  var pa = str.indexOf(pointa);

  if( pa == 0 ) return "";
  pa += pointa.length;
  var pb = str.indexOf(pointb,pa) - pa;

  return str.substr(pa,pb);
}
```

Method used for text field but fails with no error message in the console

```
var fld = document.getElementById('textfield');
var src = fld.value;
fld.oninput = function() {
  if( src.indexOf('<iframe') != -1 ) {
    fld.value = findSrc(src, 'src="', '"');
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="textfield" name="embedsrc" size="50" value="" />
```

What would be the correct method to achieve my goal?

Comment: Have you tried moving `var src = fld.value;` into the oninput function? Right now, it contains the value of the old input when the oninput function is called.

Comment: @hargasinski Yes I did try src in the oninput and still no result. I eventually got it working with the addEventListener() function.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with the following method, however if there is a better or efficient way, please inform.

The same string search function

```
function findSrc(str, pointa, pointb) 
{
  var str = " "+str;
  var pa = str.indexOf(pointa);

  if( pa == 0 ) return "";
  pa += pointa.length;
  var pb = str.indexOf(pointb,pa) - pa;

  return str.substr(pa,pb);
}
```

Created a new function

```
function getsrc() 
{
  var fld = document.getElementById('textfield');
  var src = fld.value;
  if( src.indexOf("<iframe") != -1 ) {
    fld.value = findSrc(src, 'src="', '"');
  }
}
```

HTML
Appended addEventListener to the field with call back to the new function

```
<input id="textfield" name="frmsrc" type="text" size="50" value="" />
<script>
document.getElementById("textfield").addEventListener("input", getsrc);
</script>
```